# Perfmon - Win 2008 - Recording Metric Twice!

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, performance, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I am noticing that a local perfmon I have set up to measure CPU on a Win 2008 server is actually recording two data points when recording to CPU:

```
"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (GMT Daylight Time)(-60)","\\SIA16\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
"07/06/2009 10:04:14.358"," "
"07/06/2009 10:04:44.354","3.4623040374319847"
"07/06/2009 10:04:44.369","0"
"07/06/2009 10:05:14.349","4.167729488025862"
"07/06/2009 10:05:14.365","24.961740656075715"
"07/06/2009 10:05:44.354","3.2723078398174565"
"07/06/2009 10:05:44.370","0"
"07/06/2009 10:06:14.340","3.4322359633112365"
"07/06/2009 10:06:14.371","0"
"07/06/2009 10:06:44.342","1.584632850972445"
"07/06/2009 10:06:44.373","0"
"07/06/2009 10:07:14.346","3.8717442047881967"
"07/06/2009 10:07:14.362","0"
"07/06/2009 10:07:44.343","3.4048134031355537"
"07/06/2009 10:07:44.359","0"
"07/06/2009 10:08:14.348","3.8436432760831196"
"07/06/2009 10:08:14.363","0"
"07/06/2009 10:08:44.344","3.7013401033585414"
"07/06/2009 10:08:44.360","0"
"07/06/2009 10:09:14.344","5.003598753410432"
"07/06/2009 10:09:14.360","0"
"07/06/2009 10:09:44.353","2.3193168051101831"
"07/06/2009 10:09:44.368","0"
```

Has anyone else ever seen this problem before? As you can see it does sometimes give a non-zero value for the 2nd data point, but very often zero too.

Thanks in advance, 
Ciaran

Answer (score 1):

I'm fuzzy on this, but does the _Total indicate that you're gathering information from all processors, and you have one that's idle?  Check for a Processor(0) and I think that may give you a single set of results.

Comment: I thought _Total meant an average, but I have another idea about what is going on and if I make progress on it I will post here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious to know what's going on with this...

Comment: Kara is correct. In a single-proc system, if you were to capture bot _Total and instance 0, you'd be capturing the same thing twice. If you had dual procs, and captured 0, 1, and _Total, the three values would be different, since in this case _Total would be the average for procs 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, but it seems this is, in fact, a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/perfmon/thread/f43a5987-be91-48b3-bc3e-0d5d38a01573?ppud=4). No solution has been posted from Microsoft yet, but we have had to apply a work-around as mentioned in the thread.